# xsl for sharepoint calendar

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, calendar

I need to create a calendar which will join together data from a number of separate sharepoint team calendars (it's so that the press office in my organisation can see what's happening in each department side-by-side on the same page - what they would like is something like the ui for a shared google calendar).

I have discovered that I can create a linked source in Sharepoint which combines the various calendars and will provide xml output of the data I need. So what I would like now is an example of how to consume some xml and create the standard day/week/month views in a read-only calendar to my users.

What I have discovered is the following:

You can't attach a listviewwebpart - they use caml instead of xslt - they can't consume xml data. They use the object model to consume the list that it belongs to.

No source code for that web part. It's locked in a dll.

The dataformwebpart can consume any xml data source.

Some listviewwebparts can be changed to dataformwebparts but not the calendar.

Is there an example of an xslt calendar which can consume some xml and create the standard day/week/month views to get me going?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common request, and not very easy with the standard web parts.  You could try Ton Stegeman's [Content by Type web part](http://www.tonstegeman.com/cbt/features/default.aspx) which I think allows you to roll up list items into a calendar, or alternatively take a look at (commercial) list rollup and calendar+ webparts from [Bamboo Solutions](http://bamboosolutions.com/).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ideseg.com/SharePointXSLToRenderCalendarsWithCsegRollUp.aspx
From Carlos Segura Blog, excelent way to do the Calendar Join.

Answer (score 0):

It is very common now to expect you can add another calendar as a 'layer' along with an existing one. E.g. that is what we do in Google calendar, in outlook, on android. I believe this is how it is intended, and it ends the quest for sync tools, query questions, data webparts. 
The same thing can be done in OOTB Sharepoint; see link below where they seem to have found the right answer. It is very easy to load an additional calendar once you vreated a calendar view. 
http://weblogs.asp.net/sharadkumar/archive/2010/03/12/aggregate-sharepoint-event-items-into-your-calendar-view-using-calendar-overlay.aspx